# openSubtab() URL not firing properly

Tags: visualforce, javascript, tab, console

I have a primary tab that has a subtab in it. I want to remove that subtab and open a new subtab. The new subtab is an account page. I am able to get into both `openSubtab` and `closeTab` methods. The `closeTab()` method is working but the `openSubtab` is not firing off the page open. I put an alert on it to make sure that it was firing at all and it is being called. I am not entirely sure what is happening. My thoughts are it is order of execution or my url param is not written correctly because it is in console. When I console.log my url param I get:  `/apex/001g000001jDRCiCAO`. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
            if(sforce.console.isInConsole()){
            sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, conversationSessionPrefix, true, '{!HTMLENCODE($Label.livetext__txt_conversation)}'); 

            var closeSubtab = function closeSubtab(result) {
                var tabId = result.id;
                sforce.console.closeTab(tabId);
            };
            sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(closeSubtab);

           var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
                var tabId = result.id;
                sforce.console.openSubtab(tabId , '/apex/' + accountId, true);
            };
            sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(openSubtab);
       }
```

UPDATE:
After combing through the console responses it is telling me that my ID for the subtab is invalid. I will report back when I figure out why it is invalid!

More Updates:
"openSubTab: Opening a duplicate tab is not allowed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Id was being pass incorrectly. I was getting: invalid id: scc-pt-1 for openSubtab(). This post was super helpful.

[Salesforce - Console Integration Toolkit : openSubTab: Invalid ID: scc-st-0](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139645/salesforce-console-integration-toolkit-opensubtab-invalid-id-scc-st-0)

I used `getEnclosingPrimaryTabId();` rather then `getEnclosingTabId()` for the openSubtab function. It works but it isn't very UX friendly. There is a big delay between closing the tab and opening a new tab. I might try and figure out a workaround.

```
           var closeSubtab = function closeSubtab(result) { 
                var tabId = result.id;                  
                sforce.console.closeTab(tabId, gotintoclosetab());
            };
            sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(closeSubtab);

           var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) { 
                var tabId2 = result.id;
                console.log('tabid2' + tabId2);
                sforce.console.openSubtab(tabId2, '/' + accountId, true, '' , '', gotintoopentab());
            };
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
```

Answer (score 1):

To view a record in Salesforce, it is simply "/recordId".

```
sforce.console.openSubtab(tabId , '/'+accountId, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach, let me know if that works

Here `sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(primaryTabId, true, refreshSuccess);`

```
function newContactOpenSubtab() {   
    //First find the ID of the primary tab to put the new subtab in
    sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtabCreateContact);
}

var openSubtabCreateContact = function openSubtabCreateContact(result) {
    //Now that we have the primary tab ID, we can open a new subtab in it
    var primaryTabId = result.id;

    sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(primaryTabId, true, refreshSuccess);

    sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , '/' + contactId ,true, 
        'Create Contact', null, openSuccess, 'salesforceSubtab');
};

var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
    //Report whether we succeeded in opening the subtab
    if (result.success == true) {       
    } else {        
    }
};
var refreshSuccess = function refreshSuccess(result) {
    //Report whether refreshing the primary tab was successful
    if (result.success == true) {       
    } else {        
    }
};
```